# Java AffineTransform makes drawString disappear

Tags: java, graphics2d, affinetransform

This is super-weird. When I create a BufferedImage, and do not change the Graphics2D.transform(), then I can draw a line and text with no problem.

When I do set the transform (I am setting the user space to use EMUs instead of pixels), then I can draw the line using EMU coordinates, but I can't draw text.

code here:

```
public void testBitmaps2() throws Exception {

        // no scaling
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D graphics = image.createGraphics();
        graphics.setBackground(new Color(0x00FFFFFF, true));
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        java.awt.Font javaFont = new java.awt.Font("Arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 24);
        graphics.setFont(javaFont);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        graphics.draw(new Line2D.Float(100, 150, 200, 150));
        graphics.drawString("hi there", 100, 150);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("c:/temp/", "no_scaling.png"));


        // scaling
        image = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        graphics = image.createGraphics();

        // scale to use EMUs, assuming 300DPI image
        AffineTransform scaleToEmus = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(300f / 914400f, 300f / 914400f);
        graphics.transform(scaleToEmus);

        graphics.setBackground(new Color(0x00FFFFFF, true));
        graphics.clearRect(0, 0, 914400, 914400);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        javaFont = new java.awt.Font("Arial", java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 24);
        graphics.setFont(javaFont);
        graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(914400 / 300));
        graphics.draw(new Line2D.Float(914400 / 3, 914400 / 2, 914400 * 0.666f, 914400 / 2));
        graphics.drawString("hi there", 914400 / 3, 914400 / 2);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("c:/temp/", "scaling.png"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the javadocs are wrong! [The docs say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#Font(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)):

> size - the point size of the Font

However, you need to scale it up to match the transform scaling.